# Creating a GregorianCalendar instance from milliseconds

Tags: java, timestamp, gregorian-calendar

I have a certain time in milliseconds (in a `Timestamp` object) and I want to use it to create a `GregorianCalendar` object. How can I do that?

**EDIT**: How do I do the reverse?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just get an instance of GregorianCalendar and setTime with your java.sql.Timestamp `timestamp`:

```
Calendar cal=GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(timestamp);
```

**Edit:**
As [peterh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1504556/peterh) pointed out, `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()` will not provide a `GregorianCalendar` by default, because it is inherited from`Calendar.getInstance()`, which can provide for example a `BuddhistCalendar` on some installations. To be sure to use a `GregorianCalender` use `new GregorianCalendar()` instead.

Comment: Odd as it may seem you are not guaranteed a `GregorianCalender` by calling `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()` as you do. Since the question is specifically about GregorianCalendar I think this answer is slightly incorrect. (haaduken's answer is more correct)

Answer (score 47):

To get a GregorianCalendar object and not a Calendar object. Like Michael's answer provides, you can also do the following:

```
long timestamp = 1234567890;
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
```

This assumes a UTC epoch timestamp.

Answer (score 11):

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(23423434);
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp.getTime());
```

Comment: it's worth noting that the setTimeInMillis(...) method is inherited from the Calendar class. Also, formatting the code in your answer would be helpful. :)

Comment: so if you are setting time in timestamp and then getting, why create timestamp object at all? beats me

Comment: @KalpeshSoni "I have a certain time in milliseconds (in a Timestamp object)" - OP

Answer (score 1):

I believe this works, although it may not be the best approach:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TimestampToGregorianCalendar {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(12356342); // replace with existing timestamp
        Date d = new Date(t.getTime());
        Calendar gregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        gregorianCalendar.setTime(d);
    }

}
```